# Refreshing datalist and pagenumbers using DJANGO and AJAX

Tags: ajax, django

I am trying to reload a "next page" without reloading the whole page again. I just want my datatable to be updated. I found out this is done with ajax. After doing some research on the internet I now know that your ajax/javascript goes to a certain url and in django you make the view mapped to that url return new data. Untill this point everything was clear to me. But now I had to make some sort of javascript to do that and Im completely lost.

**This is the datalist in my template**

```
<div class="project-container">
    {% for project in pagination.projects %}
        <div class="project">
            <h4 class="strong">{{ project.name }}</h4>
            <div class="project-details-vars">
                <p>{{ project.info_veld_1 }}</p>
                <p>{{ project.info_veld_2 }}</p>
                <p>{{ project.info_veld_3 }}</p>
                <p>{{ project.info_veld_4 }}</p>
                <p>{{ project.info_veld_5 }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**This is my custom paginator in my template.**

```
<div id="paginator">
    {% if pagination.prevPage %}
    <a href="/page/{{ pagination.prevPage }}">
        <img src="/static/images/arrow-left.png" />
    </a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if pagination.nextPage %}
        <a href="/page/{{ pagination.nextPage }}">
            <img src="/static/images/arrow-right.png" />
        </a>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

**Can some1 please show me a javascript that triggers on the url and that only refreshes the data on the data list AND updates the url.**

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice javascript called ajaxroutine. See this [link](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxroutine.htm). All you need to do is download the script, use

```
<script src="text/javascript" src="ajaxroutine.js"></script>
```

Then you call

```
ajaxpack.getAjaxRequest("/Example", "name=George&age=27", processGetPost, "txt")
```

in your html code, where `"/Example"` is your URL, `"name=George&age=27"` are additional parameters, `processGetPost` is a callback, a javascript function which will run after in your code after the response and `"txt"` is just to know, that the response is in txt format (I think it can also be in xml, but honestly I never tried it). This ajaxroutine works for me fine. You should try it. There's much more explanation in the link I mentioned at the begining.

Comment: This is all very clear, but my main problem is the processGetPost i guess. How to get the new variables into the schreen...

Comment: Well, you cannot use django template language. Your response has to take the data to processGetPost and in this function you have to manually create html. Some hardcore javascripting I guess. I don't know the other way to do it, sorry.